# How to add and repeat title="some text" same as alt="some text" if title is already not present?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add and repeat title="some text" same as alt="some text" if title is already not present. To show Alt text in FF also.

**before**

```
alt="some text"

alt="some text" title="some another text"
```

**After**

```
alt="some text" title="some text"

alt="some text" title="some another text"
```

**I need *

### jquery(with no conflict)

- or simple javascript code.**

Comment: The alt attribute is supposed to contain information to **replace** an image. The title attribute is supposed to contain information to **compliment** the information expressed by the element. If you want them to be the same, then there is a good chance that one of them is wrong.

Comment: Well, guess the OP just want the tooltip effect in FF with the 'alt' text for missing title.

Comment: @o.k.w — my point stands. It means the alt text is probably wrong.

Comment: @David, I agree with you too. The OP acknowledged a similar argument in one of the answers.

Comment: @David - you are right but i've made a site for client and i haven't used "title" so on mouse over tooltip is showing ALT text in IE but not in firefox, so client complaining about this he want  tool-tip on both. to save my time i'm using this

Comment: Oh no. Not one of **those** clients.

Comment: Perfect client is a myth... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**self invoking function, safe with jQuery as parameter** for conflicting `$` variable

```
(function($){
    $('img').each(function () {
        var 
            $this = $(this),
            altText  = $this.attr('alt');
        if ($this.attr('title') === '') {
            $this.attr('title', altText);
        }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: will it conflict with prototype?

Comment: that is self invoking function, jQuery object will be passed as parameter, so no conflicts will issue (no conflict with Prototype)

Answer (score 2):

Just as a side-note:

> The contents of an ALT attribute
>   should not be a tooltip (even though
>   IE displays it like this, which it
>   shouldn’t). The text should be short
>   (less than 100 words, as per WCAG
>   2.0). The text should also be relevant to the primary content so users may
>   use it INSTEAD of the image and still
>   gain the image’s value. In this case,
>   it’s an accessibility thing rather
>   than a usability thing.
>
> Source: [Proper Use Of ALT And TITLE Attributes](http://fadtastic.net/2007/04/19/proper-use-of-alt-and-title-attributes/)

The title attribute, on the other hand, is meant to provide additional information about an element.

Comment: Thanks for article although i know this very well, but for a reason i still want to use

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$("img[title='']").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('title',$(this).attr('alt'));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("img.classname").each ( function(){
        var elem = jQuery(this);
        if ( elem.attr ( "title" ) === "" )
        {
            elem.attr("title", elem.attr("alt"));
        }
    });
});
```

See **[Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)**